# import ip address in octave

Tags: import, ip-address, octave, type-conversion

I have a dataset that consists of IP addresses packets transferred etc. Octave is converting the IP addresses into float values. How do I import IP addresses as it is and what data type is to be used (String?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you import them in octave? GNU Octave has plenty of functions to load/save data. It depends how your IP adresses (IPv4 or IPv6?) are stored in your file which function is the easiest/best for you.

For example if you have a file called "ips.txt".

```
192.168.10.4
8.8.8.8
14.32.244.8
```

You could use this to get a cell:

```
octave:1> f = fopen("ips.txt", "r");
octave:2> l = textscan(f, "%s");
octave:3> fclose(f);
octave:4> 
octave:4> l{1}
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = 192.168.10.4
  [2,1] = 8.8.8.8
  [3,1] = 14.32.244.8
}
octave:5>
```

But perhaps char(fread(..)) or fgetl may be better for you dependent what you want to do later with the imported ips...

addition:
Because you commented that you have IP addresses are inside a list of floats and not a fixed scheme (a fixed scheme would be for example: "The wanted ips are at the beginning of the line, the 4.th column or somethink like that which could be processed with awk) I also add a possibility with regexp:

I created this file ips.txt:

```
192.168.10.4 some text 3.14 8.8.8.8
other 123.44 14.32.244.8
4.667.2 12.943 127.0.0.1 hello world
```

And load it with this script using regexp

```
f = fopen("ips.txt", "r");
x = char(fread(f));
fclose(f);

[S, E, TE, M, T, NM, SP] = regexp (x', '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}');
```

which gives you for M:

```
M = 
{
  [1,1] = 192.168.10.4
  [1,2] = 8.8.8.8
  [1,3] = 14.32.244.8
  [1,4] = 127.0.0.1
}
```

-- Andy

Comment: My row consist of ip Addresses as well as numeric data say in the format:

ipAddress, ipAddress, int data1,.... int datan, float data1,...float datan.
What to do in this case?

Comment: IPv4 addresses? And they are mixed without system? I can't see a fixed scheme in your comment. In this case you could use regex to extract strings which are built with (one to three digits) (dot) ... I think it would be good if you add a snippet (maybe first 5 lines?) of your file.

Comment: There is a fixed scheme for IPs. The first two columns are IPs which I need to convert to String. Here a few sample row:

1) 197.148.2.59 214.94.210.8 6 1 3552 4899 1 48 1 1141395274.903832000 1141395274.903832000
2) 161.194.73.174 199.14.135.17 17 1 1785 53 6 458 1 1141394547.311557000 1141395278.368583000
3) 211.143.181.211 140.223.154.73 6 1 443 2654 2 84 1 1141395283.726913000 1141395283.927282000
4) 94.82.131.157 165.28.40.41 6 1 1695 3128 3 462 1 1141394439.018936000 1141394440.402323000
5) 214.94.198.179 207.100.116.38 6 1 58702 25 4 240 1 1141394590.835600000 1141394632.835990000